Minimum of $xy$ in $x+y^{2}+x^{3}=1481$
Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$  such that
$$x+y^{2}+x^{3}=1481$$
What is the possible minimum value of $xy$?
Here's my attempt using lagrange multipliers (I'm not really that acquaintance of it):
Let $f(x,y)=xy$ and $g(x,y)=x^{3}+y^{2}+x-1481$
Then by lagrange multipliers,
$x=\lambda (2y)$
$y=\lambda (3x^{2}+1)$
then we get $$2y^{2}=3x^{3}+x$$
I'm not so sure where to go from here, any ideas?

Presumably, you want positive $x,y.$

@ThomasAndrews But with positive $x,y$, we can get $xy$ arbitrarily close to $0$, near the point $y=0$ and $x$ the real solution to $x+x^3=1481$.

But with negative $x,$ we can can get a smaller value of $xy$ than $0.$ @aschepler

Are you sure the question isn't for the maximum value?

If all reals are allowed, then taking $x=-M$ where $M$ is a large positive number and $y=\sqrt{1481+M+M^3}$, we can get $xy = -M\sqrt{1481+M+M^3}$ arbritarily close to $-\infty$.  If negatives are not allowed, then as mentioned above this is $0$ or arbitrarily close to it.  Is the question reproduced correctly?

If $x,y _in \mathbb{R}$, then the minimum does not exist. Just chose $x <0$ then $y = \sqrt{1481 -x -x^3} \implies xy = x\sqrt{1481 -x -x^3} \le \sqrt{1481}\cdot x$. Take $x \to -\infty $ and you will obtain $xy < \sqrt{1481}\cdot x \to -\infty $.

Let $M=\lbrace (x,y)~|~ x+x^3+y^2=1481 \rbrace$. We define the following mapping
$$ 
 \begin{array}{rcl}
  f ~:~ \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
  (x,y) & \longmapsto & x+x^3+y^2-1481
 \end{array}    
 $$
$f$ is clearly a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}-$submersion. We have that $M=f^{-1}(\lbrace  0\rbrace)=M \cap \mathbb{R}^2$ so $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of dimension $1$ and class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. Let $g$ be the mapping such that
$$ 
 \begin{array}{rcl}
  g ~:~ \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
  (x,y) & \longmapsto & xy
 \end{array}    
 $$
$g$ is also $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a relative extrema of $g|_M$, it exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
x_0 = \lambda (2y_0) \\
y_0 = \lambda (3x_0^2+1)
\end{cases}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases}
x_0 = \lambda (2y_0) \\
3y_0^2 = 2x_0^3+1481
\end{cases}
$$
I don't think the next step is possible without some form of heavy calculation. Then you take the $(x_0 ,y_0)$ such that $3y_0^2-2x_0^3=1481$ so that $x_0y_0$ is minimal.

This feels like you're saying "yes, I agree you should use Lagrange multipliers" but dressed up in fancy language.

@Aaron True. But I think using Lagrange multipliers require some form of justification. That's why I wrote this.

Don't forget the original constraint. Combine
$$x+y^{2}+x^{3}=1481$$
and
$$2y^{2}=3x^{3}+x$$
to
get
$$2(1481-x-x^3)=3x^3+x$$
Solution here.
And full $(x,y,\lambda)$ here.

That's two critical points. Now time to see if each is a relative minimum or relative maximum or neither, and look at edge and unbounded limits.
